# Passing variables between views opened using programatic storyboard

Tags: ios, objective-c, variables, global-variables

I am currently opening my new view using the following code:

```
NSString * storyboardName = @"Main";
UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:storyboardName bundle: nil];
UIViewController * vc = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"secondViewController"];
[self presentViewController:vc animated:YES completion:nil];
```

I would like to be able to pass the value of a variable to the SecondViewController using code similar to that posted below:

```
ViewControllerB *viewControllerB = [[ViewControllerB alloc] initWithNib:@"ViewControllerB" bundle:nil];
viewControllerB.isSomethingEnabled = YES;
[self pushViewController:viewControllerB animated:YES];
```

But I am new to Objective-C & iOS coding, and do not know how. So how can I change the value of a variable in the SecondViewController to be the value of the variable in the FirstViewController using the code I already have (first block of code). All help appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming your second view controller is of type MyCustomViewController, change

```
UIViewController * vc = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"secondViewController"];
```

to

```
MyCustomViewController * vc = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"secondViewController"];
```

Unrelated note, I would change

```
MyCustomViewController * vc = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"secondViewController"];
```

to

```
MyCustomViewController * vc = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:NSStringFromClass([MyCustomViewController class])];
```

You'll need to change the identifier in storyboard to match. If you do this you'll be retaining some type information instead of using a flimsy hardcoded string. (FYI none of this code is tested, just wrote it out here.)

Comment: First part works like a charm! Thanks a lot :) Oh, but the second part errors with "Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Storyboard (<UIStoryboard: 0x7f857972b8c0>) doesn't contain a view controller with identifier 'SecondViewController''". But I expect it would work if I changed the identifier to "SecondViewController". Thanks nonetheless!

Comment: Yea, you need to change the storyboard identifier to match and I highly recommend you follow that pattern, it will pay off down the road. ;) Since you found this answer helpful, would you mind accepting it as the answer?